# In STS - spring tool suite, war files are not showing up to add in tomcat?

Tags: maven, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I ran the clean and install commands and I can see the war file gets generated. But I am unable to add it to the tomcat server in STS. In the add modules option of the server, the war is not showing up. Has anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project is set to "facetted form" (right click project name, "Properties", "Project Facets") and enable "Dynamic Web Project". After that you can even add your project to the server by drag and drop.

For Spring-Boot projects better use the "Boot Dashboard" (click "Window", "show view", "other", "Spring Boot Dashboard".